# Layout does not fit on all screen

Tags: android, android-layout, size, screen, screen-orientation

I've created an xml layout in my android project, but it does not fit on all screens.
Is there any way to fit it on all screens?

Here is the layout content:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp">
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/unlock" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:id="@+id/imageButton1"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton3"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton4"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton6"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton7"></ImageButton>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton5"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton8"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton9"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton10"></ImageButton>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton11"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton12"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton13"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton14"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/lockicon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton15"></ImageButton>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: use LinearLayout with layout_weight attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  setting the width of `TableRow` to `match_parent` for all rows. Also add weights to all the `ImageButton` components.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TableLayout` use `android:layout_weightSum` and then in the 3 children, specify the weights you desire.

The problem is, Your first child has a constant measurement of 100dp. So this will not work on all screen sizes because they're changing and your measurement specifications are not.

Comment: weightSum is optional

Comment: @Tobor Yeah but it's easier to use weights when you specify a weightsum. Otherwise the attribute wouldnt exist

Comment: By default, the weightSum (if not specified) **IS** the sum of the specified weights.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton10"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton11"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton12"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton13"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton14"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton15"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```